# `sortProperty` attribute is not sorting `sap.m.table`

Tags: sorting, sapui5

I'm trying to add a sorting feature on each column of a table. I have inspected the example provided by SAPUI5 explored here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview

Specifically I added a `sortProperty` attribute to the column element in my XML-view (see `Qty` below), but I don't see any sorting functionality nor any sorting arrows like in the example provided. Could someone examine what I'm missing here?

```xml
<Table id="searchResultsTable"
               selectionMode="MultiToggle"
               visible="true"
               items="{
                path: '/ProductCollection',
                sorter: {
                    path: 'AwdDate',
                    descending: true  
                }
            }">
    <columns>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="7%" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Awd Date" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="5%" demandPopin="false" hAlign="Left">
            <FormattedText htmlText="CAGE" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Vendor" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="4%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Type" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="4%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="PRC" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="4%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="EX" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="6%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="PPI Cost" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="6%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Hist Cost" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="4%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="true">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Unit" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="10%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="PIIN" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="5%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false" sortProperty="Qty">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Qty" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="6%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Hist PPI" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="6%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="Curr PPI" />
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" width="10%" hAlign="Left" demandPopin="false">
            <FormattedText htmlText="PPI Factor" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{AwdDate}"/>
                <Text text="{CAGE}" />
                <Text text="{Vendor}" />
                <Text text="{Type}" />
                <Text text="{PRC}" />
                <Text text="{EX}" />
                <Text text="${PPICost}" />
                <Text text="${HistCost}" />
                <Text text="{Unit}" Style="font-color:red" />
                <Link        text="{PIIN}"
                        press="handleLinkPress" app:mydata="{HistPPI},{Qty},{AwdDate}" />
                <Text text="{Qty}" />
                <Text text="{HistPPI}" />
                <Text text="{CurrentPPI}" />
                <Text text="{PPIConversionFactor}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

The explored example you have mentioned uses the `sap.ui.table.Table` library and it appears that you are using the `table` control from the `sap.m` library.

The `sap.m.table` control does not have the same built-in sorting functionality as `sap.ui.table.Table`. You can implement sorting by following [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/preview), alternatively you could consider switching to use the [`sap.ui.table.Table`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.table.Table.html) control if it is suitable for your application.